# How to stop LiveData observer from firing automatically in Android MVVM architecture?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Consider the following scenario. I have two fragments, `FormFragment` and `SelectionFragment` that are hosted by `MainActivity`. I have a `SharedViewModel` that I plan on using for data communication between the fragments.

`FormFragment` has a spinner, tapping on which opens up the `SelectionFragment`.

`SelectionFragment` consists of a RecyclerView that has a list of `Item` objects.

`SharedViewModel` has two LiveDatas, `LiveData<Item> selectedItem` and `LiveData<List<Item>> items`

Use case:

1. On app launch, user lands on the `FormFragment` which has a spinner with no selected item
2. When user taps on the spinner, we navigate to `SelectionFragment`
3. `SelectionFragment` gets the list of items from the `SharedViewModel` and populates the RecyclerView
4. When user taps on an item, we update the `selectedItem` in the `SharedViewModel` and pop the `SelectionFragment` from the back stack to go back to the `FormFragment`
5. `FormFragment` spinner now shows the selected item
6. User can select a different item by performing the same process

Problem:

After completing steps 1 to 5 above, when we try to choose another item by performing Step 1 again, the observer inside `SelectionFragment` immediately fires (since `selectedItem` is not `null`), and pops the fragment from the back stack. This is obviously not the desired behaviour since we want the user to be able to select a different item at will.

How can I properly observe the `selectedItem` inside `SelectionFragment` so it doesn't cause its observer to fire immediately?

```java
class FormFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.spinner) protected Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SharedViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);

        viewModel.getSelectedItem().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), selectedItem -> {
            spinner.setSelected(selectedItem);
        });

        spinner.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // navigate to SelectionFragment
            requireFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new SelectionFragment()).commit();
        });
    }
}

class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_view) protected RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter();

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SharedViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);

        viewModel.getItems().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), items -> {
            // load items into recycler view
            adapter.submitList(new ArrayList<>(items));
        });

        viewModel.getSelectedItem().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), selectedItem -> {
            // pop fragment from back stack
            requireFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        });

        adapter.setOnItemClickedListener(item -> {
            // update selected item in view model when user taps on an item in the list
            viewModel.setSelectedItem(item);
        });

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<Item> selectedItem = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private Repository repository;

    // repository is injected (unimportant to the problem)
    SharedViewModel(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    LiveData<List<Item>> getItems() {
        return repository.getItems();
    }

    LiveData<Item> getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

    void setSelectedItem(Item item) {
        selectedItem.setValue(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `FormFragment`, after you read the data from the `SelectionFragment`, set it to `null` in the `LIveData` object.

Alternatively, you could wrap your objects in a `Consumable`, something like this

```
class ConsumableValue<T>(private val data: T) {

    private var consumed = false

    @UiThread
    fun consume(block: ConsumableValue<T>.(T) -> Unit) {
        val wasConsumed = consumed
        consumed = true
        if (!wasConsumed) {
            this.block(data)
        }
    }

    @UiThread
    fun ConsumableValue<T>.release() {
        consumed = false
    }
}
```